# NoClassDefFound React Native Library Install Android

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-modules

I am trying to install https://github.com/theopolisme/react-native-stripe-terminal on a fresh react native init project. When I try to initialize the library I get the following runtime error.

```
Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNStripeTerminal': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.reactnative_stripeterminal.Constants, js engine: hermes
```

From my research it seems that package is not install properly. But I've tried both Auto Linking and manual installation with the same error. It doesn't seem like this library is very well maintained, but it could also be user error. I'm using react 67.4 and Java 11 on a Macbook M1. Current manual installation below.

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-stripe-terminal')
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.stripeterminaldemo;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.reactnative_stripeterminal.RNStripeTerminalPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.stripeterminaldemo.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            packages.add(new RNStripeTerminalPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  private final ReactNativeHost mNewArchitectureNativeHost =
      new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this);

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      return mNewArchitectureNativeHost;
    } else {
      return mReactNativeHost;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the TurboModule system
    ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.stripeterminaldemo.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'StripeTerminalDemo'
include ':react-native-stripe-terminal'
project(':react-native-stripe-terminal').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-stripe-terminal/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')

if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
}
```